# Could not find or load main class s1p1.S1P1

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new to NetBeans and Java. I am trying to create a simple script that repeats whatever is put in the "System.out.println()" function, but I keep running into a single error.
Here is my code:

```
//create a class named S1P1
public class S1P1 {
    //this is the main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //this prints out whatever is below.
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

I have absolutely no idea what the issue is, but I keep getting the error, " Error: Could not find or load main class s1p1.S1P1".

[image]

Comment: Get rid of the habit of putting numbers in class names right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java expects a package declaration to locate the class in the folder `s1p1`. Add

```
package s1p1;
```